# Kubernetes pod that runs kubectl get deploy returns connection error

Tags: kubernetes

I have a pod that runs `kubectl get deploy <Deployment Name>`. However, the pod doesn’t get created, and returns the message below.

```
The connection to the server 172.20.0.1:443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

Which permission do I have to add as a serviceaccount ?

Comment: it appears you do not have the `KUBECONFIG` set correctly. based on the error, none of your `kubectl` commands will work. you can try `kubectl get pods` for example.

Comment: Is your `kube-apiserver` listening on that IP and port ?